# Find 2nd highest salary in every department

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a schema Employee(Employeeid,Name,departmentid,salary). I want to find out 2nd highest salary in each department.

```
select DepartmentID,name,salary from 
(select Departmentid,name,salary, rank() over 
(partition by departmentid order by salary desc)as 
Rank from employee)t where t.Rank=2;
```

This does the job but if there is only 1 employee in a department then it does not printout that salary. Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use `Count() over()` analytic function to count the records in each department. When the count is `1` then take Rank `1`

```
SELECT departmentid, 
       NAME, 
       salary 
FROM   (SELECT departmentid, 
               NAME, 
               salary, 
               Dense_rank()OVER (partition BY departmentid 
                              ORDER BY salary DESC) AS Rank, 
               Count(1)OVER(partition BY departmentid) AS cnt 
        FROM   employee)t 
WHERE  t.rank = 2 
        OR ( t.rank = 1 
             AND cnt = 1 )
```

**Note :** I have used `DENSE_RANK` over `RANK` because, when there is a *TIE* in first salary you will not get `RANK = 2`

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you explain me the count(1) thing here?

Comment: `Count(1) over(partition..` will count the number of records in each `department`.

Comment: Hey what about the situation when 2 records have same salary.Then the rank for both would be same  and the count would be 2.

Comment: ID  Name Salary Rank Count
    12022         Abc  9000 1     2
    12022         EFG  9000 1     2

Comment: @AmberO Rather than using COUNT(), this should work for cases like that: `OR T.Rank = 1 AND T.salary = (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM employee WHERE departmentid = T.departmentid)`. Alternatively, changed the count to another dense_rank() that orders by salary in ascending order, e.g. `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentid ORDER BY salary) AS Rank2` and say `OR t.Rank = 1 AND t.Rank2 = 1`

Comment: @ZLK In the situation where 2 employees of same department has same salary this returns both the tuples.

Comment: @AmberO Is it only meant to return one? You'd need to decide whether you want it to return a random name or a particular name over others if that's the case. If you're fine with just returning any random name, then just replace DENSE_RANK() with ROW_NUMBER().